# Can anyone explain why event type is an arbitrary string in seam?

Tags: events, seam

I noticed that the event type is just an arbitrary string in seam which will be used in component.xml or annotations. Sometimes it is error-prone if I missspell them, for example "org.jboss.seam.security.notLogedIn", actually it should be "org.jboss.seam.security.notLoggedIn". Is there any alternative way to handle event types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since most of the event keys (types) are declared as `public static final` (as the one you reference), you can reference them without having troubles of misspelling.

```
@Observer(Identity.EVENT_NOT_LOGGED_IN)
public void handleNotLoggedIn() {
}
```

Unfortunately, you **cannot** use EL in event type declaration in `component.xml`. I recently tried that.

```
<event type="#{...}">
    <!-- does not work -->
</event>
```

There is, IMHO, no other way than copy-and-paste the event keys into the `component.xml` to prevent misspelling.

Comment: Thank you very much, kraftan, that is exactly what I want.